# Adding a delimiter after each file processed within awk

Tags: awk, gawk, nawk

I have multiple files where I am extracting text between two delimiters (START and END non-inclusive).  After I process each file I want to output a delimiter indicating the file was processed, say the string "END".  How would I add the string "END" to the output after each processed file?  For example,

Say I have two files with the content

### file1.txt

```
line 1
line 2
START
I want to extract this text
and this text
END
line 3
line 4
```

and

### file2.txt

```
line10
line20
START
I also want this text.
END
line 30
```

I know if I execute the following:

```
awk '/START/,/END/{if (!/START/&&!/END/) print}' test*.txt
```

I will get the following output:

```
I want to extract this text
and this text
I also want this text.
```

But the output I want is:

```
I want to extract this text
and this text
END
I also want this text.
END
```

How do I get the string "END" added to the output after each file is processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FNR==1 && NR!=1 {print "END"}
END {print "END"}
```

So you'd have:

```
awk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1 {print "END"} /START/,/END/{if (!/START/&&!/END/) print} END {print "END"}' test*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

the variable FNR is reset to 0 on every new file, so you could have a rule trigger on (FNR==0 && NR!=0):

```
(FNR==0) && (NR!=0) {
  print "END"
}
END {
  print "END"
}
```

Comment: OK, not sure on the indexing issue and no awk handy. Trust Dennis :)

Answer (score 0):

You're asking awk to skip printing END.  Stop that.

```
awk '/START/,/END/{if (!/START/) print}' test*.txt
```